# How to prevent Screen Orientation change when Activity finishes on Android 8.1 Version Devices?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, google-nexus, android-8.1-oreo, google-pixel

I'm working on an app and encountered a strange behavior on 8.1 Devices (Pixel2, Nexus5x), so I wrote a small App to verify this behavior.

`MainActivity` is locked to `portrait` mode while `LandscapeActivity` is locked to `landscape`. `MainActivity` starts the `LandscapeActivity` for Result. Screen Switches from `portrait` to `landscape` as expected. When `LandscapeActivity` is finished it propagates the Result to `MainActivity`, while switching back to `portrait` (as expected).

But Sometimes I encounter kind of a bug here. After `onActivityResult` in `MainActivity` it switches from `portrait` to `landscape` to switch back to `portrait` immediately. While I can handle the state, it still looks  nasty.

For traceability I will post everything to rebuild it.

What can I do to prevent it? Also note that it does not happen every time, and as far as I can test on 8.1 devices ONLY. It seems fine on android devices below 8.1

**EDIT:**
Added `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to my manifest as @Floern suggested in his answer without success.
A confirmation on a platform bug will be an acceptable answer, too

Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LandscapeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>

    </application>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int REQ_CODE = 878;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: savedInstanceState=" + savedInstanceState + ", orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LandscapeActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: orientation=" + orientation());
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Result=" + data.getStringExtra(LandscapeActivity.KEY_DATA), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    String orientation(){
        return getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ?  "Landscape" : "Portrait";
    }
}
```

LandscapeActivity

```
public class LandscapeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static final String TAG = LandscapeActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String KEY_DATA = "DATA";
    static int COUNTER = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: savedInstanceState=" + savedInstanceState + "orientation=" + (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ?  "Landscape" : "Portrait"));
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                COUNTER++;
                data.putExtra(KEY_DATA, "Runned " + COUNTER + " times");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: orientation=" + orientation());
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    String orientation(){
        return getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ?  "Landscape" : "Portrait";
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.example.com.orientationtest8_1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

layout `activity_main` File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="android.dermalog.com.orientationtest8_1.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And last a Log from clicking on Buttons repeatadly:

```
01-04 15:18:06.744  D/MainActivity: onCreate: savedInstanceState=null
01-04 15:18:06.847  D/MainActivity: onStart: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:06.850  D/MainActivity: onResume: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:14.036  D/MainActivity: onPause: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:14.108  D/LandscapeActivity: onCreate: savedInstanceState=nullorientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:14.139  D/LandscapeActivity: onStart: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:14.141  D/LandscapeActivity: onResume: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:14.217  D/MainActivity: onStop: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:15.643  D/LandscapeActivity: onPause: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:15.711  D/MainActivity: onActivityResult: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:15.719  D/MainActivity: onStart: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:15.720  D/MainActivity: onResume: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:15.786  D/LandscapeActivity: onStop: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:15.786  D/LandscapeActivity: onDestroy: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:18.036  D/MainActivity: onPause: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:18.097  D/LandscapeActivity: onCreate: savedInstanceState=nullorientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:18.121  D/LandscapeActivity: onStart: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:18.123  D/LandscapeActivity: onResume: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:18.213  D/MainActivity: onStop: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:19.505  D/LandscapeActivity: onPause: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:19.564  D/MainActivity: onActivityResult: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:19.569  D/MainActivity: onStart: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:19.569  D/MainActivity: onResume: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:19.639  D/LandscapeActivity: onStop: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:19.640  D/LandscapeActivity: onDestroy: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:20.102  D/MainActivity: onPause: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:20.103  D/MainActivity: onStop: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:20.104  D/MainActivity: onDestroy: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:20.123  D/MainActivity: onCreate: savedInstanceState=Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[{android:views={16908290=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3, 2131165191=android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState@3c34340, 2131165193=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3, 2131165199=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3, 2131165219=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3, 2131165229=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3}}], android:lastAutofillId=1073741823, android:fragments=android.app.FragmentManagerState@c215279}]
01-04 15:18:20.149  D/MainActivity: onStart: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:20.152  D/MainActivity: onResume: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:20.699  D/MainActivity: onPause: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:20.701  D/MainActivity: onStop: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:20.702  D/MainActivity: onDestroy: orientation=Landscape
01-04 15:18:20.718  D/MainActivity: onCreate: savedInstanceState=Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[{android:views={16908290=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3, 2131165191=android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$SavedState@807af46, 2131165193=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3, 2131165199=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3, 2131165219=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3, 2131165229=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@7ceec3}}], android:lastAutofillId=1073741823, android:fragments=android.app.FragmentManagerState@8d12507}]
01-04 15:18:20.748  D/MainActivity: onStart: orientation=Portrait
01-04 15:18:20.751  D/MainActivity: onResume: orientation=Portrait
```

Comment: So , it has no method to avoid ? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [bug](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/576262) was fixed. So waiting for next release/patch.

Comment: can you please let us know the release number where this issue completly fixed?

Comment: Is this issue fixed?

Comment: Won't Fix (Obsolete): The issue is no longer relevant due to changes in the product. from https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/life-of-a-bug#no-action-issues

Comment: @Rafael T please check my answer.

Comment: They said it was fixed on 30 Jan 2019.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, This is an issue in Android 8.1 OS version. As this was made obsolete. we can have a work around for these kind of issues. In this particular API level , Android OS might be storing the latest orientation value and is being applied to all the screens until the previous screen or that particular screen is destroyed. So, the work around for this type of issue is to change the orientation before going back to the screen .

**for ex:**
*If ScreenA is in portrait mode and screenB is in landscape mode and if screen is moved to ScreenB which is Landscape and if you come back to ScreenA without killing ScreenB (restoring ScreenA), screenA also be visible in Landscape.*

 To fix this issue, force change the orientation of ScreenA to Portrait in **onPause()** or **OnStop()** of  ScreenB(to restore ScreenA).

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

after this call, ScreenA will be in portrait.
Also, in onResume() of ScreenB,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```

Comment: What about in screen which we have no control? Like going to email or sharing text in social media. We have no control in the code of those apps

Comment: @Pops this issue will be caused only if screenA's orientation is different to ScreenB and both should be restricted to single type. i.e eitehr portrait or landscape. In your question, if screen moves out of your app, nothing might happen.

Comment: Imagine all my screens are in landscape orientation and we have a button for sharing our message in the app. When we tap the button to go to message app/whatsapp and change the phone to portrait mode, now the message app will be in portrait mode. When we come back to our app the landscape screen will be shown in portrait and we can't fix this issue with your solution above.

Comment: Yes. I faced the same issue. But this is the solution we can get . this worked for me. can you post your code. will check

Answer (score 2):

This might indeed be a framework bug. I noticed similar behavior on Samsung devices while using the camera app (via Intent) in landscape from a portrait-only app. I couldn't figure out what exactly the cause is, but I found a work-around that minimizes the effect.

If you tell the system you want to handle the orientation change yourself, by adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to your Activity, it won't be recreated on orientation change. Thus you can avoid the overhead of recreating the Activity (twice), which may improve the performance up to the point that you don't notice the orientation change at all.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Comment: Hey, In my original app I'm using a camera in landscape too, thats why I wrote the sample above to make shure it has nothing to do with it. Regarding your `configChanges`: I tried it in my sample, but got still the same behavior. I will edit it in my original question to prevent others trying it

Comment: Does the activity still get recreated on orientation change? If so it might be another instance of the same Activity class. NB my Activity has `android:launchMode="singleTask"`, but I don't think that has an effect on this..

Comment: exactly! I also played with launchMode `singleTask`, `singleTop` and `singleInstance` without any change. Note that this happens on 8.1 devices ONLY. If it IS a framework bug, how to get it confirmed?

Comment: Do you guys get any help ?